# What is causing visudo to fail with: "visudo: can't stat <filename>: Bad file number"?

Tags: linux, solaris, sudo, aix

We use the `#include` feature in the sudoers file for organizing our sudo rules on a per-application basis.

Our sudoers set up looks kinda like this:

```
/etc/sudoers
 -> #include /usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master
     -> #include /usr/local/etc/sudo/app1.sudo
     -> #include /usr/local/etc/sudo/app2.sudo
     -> #include /usr/local/etc/sudo/<...etc...>.sudo
```

`/usr/local/etc` is a directory we sync across all of our servers.

Sometimes we need host-specific sudo rules, so we put those directly into /etc/sudoers. Everything global goes into those centrally synced files.

When I run `visudo` to edit the local sudoers, it opens `/etc/sudoers` in vi without a problem. When I save my changes, I get prompted with:

```
"/etc/sudoers.tmp" XX lines, XXXX characters 
press return to edit /usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master: 
visudo: can't stat /usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master: Bad file number
```

And then visudo just exists (exit code 1).

The syntax for the `sudoers.master` and `appX.sudo` files all check out.

What is causing visudo to fail to follow through with opening the `sudoers.master` file that was included via the `#include` at the end of the base sudoers?

I'm seeing this behavior on AIX, Linux, and Solaris.

As a work-around, is there a way to tell visudo to just not follow any `#include` directives, and only edit the primary file?

Comment: Does `visudo -f /usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master` work OK? This might indicate if this is an issue with that file/directory specifically or the general issue of multiple include files in your environment.

Comment: Could it be an `selinux` issue with editing files outside `/etc/`? Anything in the selinux audit log?

Comment: Calling `visudo -f /usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master` works fine. It even follows `#include`s to the other sudo files in the same directory with out a problem.

I don't think it's an `selinux` issue, as I can repeat the same behavior on AIX and Solaris. (Also, we have selinux disabled.)

Comment: So not an issue with handling `#include` files in general or access to `/usr/local/etc/sudo/sudoers.master`. Only thing I can think of is odd characters somewhere around the `#include` statement in `/etc/sudoers` (though I'd expect that to be picked up by syntax check). Have you tried looking for oddities using `:se list` when in `vi`?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `#includedir` rather than `#include` `visudo` won't try to edit the included files unless they have syntax errors.

Comment: We had discussed about using `#includedir`, but we opted against it since we felt having a "master" control file for sudoers would give a bit more finer-grained control over how new applications get added in.